# Is it possible to retrieve all logs messages store them into a file or show them at the end of an ETL Job?

Tags: java, logging, groovy, jedox

**Introduction :**

I work on a tool called Jedox. In this tool there is an ETL. This ETL can run job(job allow to execute multiple step from the ETL, by step I mean a set of operation on a table(most of the time)). Some jobs can just launch successively different step from etl, but there is another type of job than can run script. I try to run a job that use Groovy language. This language is very similar to Java, the two language share many similarity.

**Context :**

During the run, the ETL show message logs on a console. I can also print some message myself. Ex `LOG.info("hello")` will print `Hello` in the ETL Jedox Console. LOG is an object from the class ETLLogger. It's a specific class from Jedox library.

**Question :**

1. With this logger, how can I get messages logs printed during the
   job's run ?
2. With another Logger(from log4j for example) is it possible to get
   ALL logs message printed during a process ?

**Goal :**

I want those logs messages to print all the warnings happened during the job at the END of the job, because jedox console is very glitchy and I can't retrieve decent data from a simple copy and paste. Furthermore, if a just copy/paste all logs I had select only warning message manually. And if it's possible I want to write the logs that interest me in a file, it would be great !

**Bonus :**
Here's a visual of Jedox ETL Console.
[image]

Comment: according to official doc https://knowledgebase.jedox.com/on-prem/logs.htm#Integrator there is a logger configuration in jedox.  usually it allows you to setup additional log files. in yur case you could store all warnings+ into a separate file where you could search...

Comment: How do I store all those logs in a file ?

Comment: i'm just reading doc that is saying that logs already in the file. i don't have jedox in my hands. you have to go to jedox server check corresponding logging config that should point to a file with logs.

Comment: In fact there is a logfile but on jedox cloud instance this file isn't available in the cloud sever, it's only available on another website by clicking on a button to download it. So I can request this logfile.

Answer (score -1):

The Jedox ETL - Integrator comes with an own API, where the logger is an additional class.
If you are working with the Groovy Job envrionment, than you have full access to all of the Classes and Methods. In your case the State Class would be helpful to get all Wanrnings or Errors of your current job/subjob. You can write the state items them to a seperate File or collect them into a Varialbe for further useage, as a example. The target can be a file, database or even a jedox olap cube.

Starting Point of the Groovy Scripting API:
https://knowledgebase.jedox.com/integration/integrator-scripting-api.htm

Here is API Documentation of all Jedox ETL Classes:
https://software.jedox.com/doc/2022_2/jedox_integrator_scripting_api_doc_2022_2/com/jedox/etl/components/scriptapi/package-summary.html

Comment: Most of the time, if you're affiliated with something to which you link or recommend, then we require disclosure of affiliation. However, the links you've included here appear to be to official documentation for something asked about in the question. In such specific cases, disclosure of affiliation is *not* required.  We do think such disclosure (a simple ", which I wrote" is good) is beneficial to you and people reading your answer, but it's *not* required.

Answer (score -1):

How do I store all those logs in a file ?
In Jedox you can create a new File-Load, which can be triggered by the 'main' groovy job.
A good point to start is here:
https://knowledgebase.jedox.com/integration/loads/file-load.htm

Comment: Please don't use the "Post Your Answer" button to submit content which does not attempt to answer the question at the top of this page. If you want to respond to a comment, you have to earn enough reputation to post a comment yourself first by posting enough legitimate questions, actual answers, and/or edit suggestions.